# How to set row height in inches using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, document, xlsxwriter

How to set row height in inches using `xlsxwriter`?
I'm trying to copy a document cell by cell, but I have values of length and width of cells in inches.
Like this: `worksheet.set_row('A1', '1.25"', '0.15"')`

Comment: From the [`set_row()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#set_row) documentation it looks like the `height` is specified in terms of the number of whole rows of the sheet the row in in — so it doesn't have concrete spatial units. I say that because that's consistent with the `width` parameter passed [`set_column()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#set_column) which is the number of columns to be spanned (not inches or centimeters)

Answer (score 1):

you can use set_row_pixels() method.

if you want to widen 1st row to 30 pixels:

```
worksheet.set_row_pixels(0,30)
```

if you want to widen 1st col to 30 pixels:

`worksheet.set_column_pixels("A:A", 30)`

as the documentation says set_row and set_columns widen by character size unit.
but if you want to convert pixels to inches, it depends on the resolution(Pixels per inch (ppi)).
here is the formula :

`pixel_value = inch_value * ppi`